# Existence of formula for the sum of the first n terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given any series, does a formula for the sum of the first n terms always exist?If it does, are there any series for which such formula is unknown?

Comment: there does not exist any closed formula for Harmonic numbers, or even the sum of the first $n$ prime numbers (I'm talking about finitely many prime numbers)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want something more explicit that $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$? Then no, in a generic case an algebraic expression that does not involve symbols $\sum$ or $\prod$ does not exist. It cannot, as the set of real-valued sequences is bigger (in the sense of cardinality) than the set of algebraic formulas (using a predetermined, finate set of symbols).

For example, expression $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$ cannot really be simplified. It defines what is called harmonic numbers, but there is no simpler algebraic formula for them. There are some analytic formulas, for example
$$ H_n = \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} dx$$
but in generic case, even this does not exist.